# Inserting a regexp() SQLite function in Haskell (Database.SQLite3,"direct-sqlite")

Tags: regex, function, haskell, sqlite

I need to create an implementation of the `regex()` SQLite function in a Haskell database connection so that I can use the "REGEX" operator in queries.

Now, I have an implementation of a regex matching function that uses PCRE:

```
import Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike
import qualified Text.Regex.PCRE.ByteString as PCRE
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

sqlRegex :: BS.ByteString -> BS.ByteString -> IO Bool
sqlRegex reg b = do
    reC <- pcreCompile reg
    re <- case reC of
        (Right r) -> return r
    reE <- PCRE.execute re b
    case reE of
        (Right (Just _)) -> return True
        (Right (Nothing)) -> return False
    where pcreCompile = PCRE.compile defaultCompOpt defaultExecOpt
```

which works well (please excuse the very explicit calls)

```
> sqlRegex (Data.ByteString.Char8.pack ".*") (Data.ByteString.Char8.pack "hello")
True
> sqlRegex (Data.ByteString.Char8.pack "H.*") (Data.ByteString.Char8.pack "hello")
False
```

Now, how do I create the SQLite function??

```
conn <- open $ pack dbFile
createFunction conn "regexp" (Just 2) True [..... and what should go here?]
```

The [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/direct-sqlite-2.3.17/docs/Database-SQLite3.html#createFunction) for `createFunction` 
[image: createFunction API docs]
helps me as far as making me understand that I need to make the function take a context and some arguments, but the refs for those data does not help me at all!
[image: FuncContext and FuncArgs API docs]

How should make my function take a `FuncContext` and `FuncArgs`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example in the github repo:

https://github.com/IreneKnapp/direct-sqlite/blob/master/test/Main.hs#L743-757

```
-- implements repeat(n,str)
repeatString ctx args = do
    n <- funcArgInt64 args 0
    s <- funcArgText args 1
    funcResultText ctx $ T.concat $ replicate (fromIntegral n) s
```

You use the functions `funcArg...` to get the arguments and functions like `funcResult...` to return them.

Links to the docs:

- [Extract Function Arguments](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/direct-sqlite-2.3.17/docs/Database-SQLite3-Direct.html#g:10)
- [Set the Result of a Function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/direct-sqlite-2.3.17/docs/Database-SQLite3-Direct.html#g:11)

Comment: Excellent! Very helpful! Thanks!